# How to use BeginExecuteReader

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Good day.

Please, help me about how to use three methods BeginExecuteReader() of SqlCommand class, using Generic Lists. I made a method using BeginExecuteReader, but i don't know if this is the best way of usage

```
public class Empresa {
    public Empresa() {
        PkEmpresa = -1;
        CodigoEmpresa = "";
        Descripcion = "";
        PkCategoriaEmpresa = -1;
    }

    public int PkEmpresa { get; set; }
    public string CodigoEmpresa { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public int PkCategoriaEmpresa { get; set; }

    public Empresa ShallowCopy() {
        return (Empresa)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}



public class AsyncronousDAL {
    private static string getConexion() {
        return "Data Source=DATABASE;Initial Catalog=DATA_BASE;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing=True";
    }

    public static List<Empresa> ConsultaAsincrona() {
        List<Empresa> _resultados = new List<Empresa>();

        using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(getConexion())) {
            using (SqlCommand commando = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[pruebaAsync]", conexion)) {
                commando.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                conexion.Open();
                IAsyncResult resultado = commando.BeginExecuteReader();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = commando.EndExecuteReader(resultado)) {
                    while (reader.Read()) {
                        _resultados.Add(new Empresa() {
                            PkEmpresa = Convert.ToInt32(reader["PkEmpresa"]),
                            CodigoEmpresa = reader["CodigoEmpresa"].ToString(),
                            Descripcion = reader["Descripcion"].ToString(),
                            PkCategoriaEmpresa = Convert.ToInt32(reader["PkCategoriaEmpresa"])
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return _resultados;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to block anyway, why aren't you just using `ExecuteReader`?

Comment: how i can make it for don't block?

Comment: You'd have to completely rewrite your function to take in a callback function. You can't avoid blocking if you're going to return the `List<Empresa>` directly because this requires the list to be available. If you're making the function asynchronous, the list is by definition not available yet,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you aren't familiar with the Asynch pattern there are lots of tutorials and examples on the web.  This is old, but still relevant:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719595(v=vs.71).aspx

When you call `BeginExecuteReader` that work is going to end up being pushed out to a worker thread, allowing your main to continue executing.  When you call `EndExecuteReader` that will cause your main thread to block until that task is complete.

If you immediately called EndExecuteReader - you aren't really getting any benefit (in fact, you're introducing additional overhead).

Take a look at the example here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szdt0kc.aspx

> The BeginExecuteReader method returns immediately, but until the code
>   executes the corresponding EndExecuteReader method call, it must not
>   execute any other calls that start a synchronous or asynchronous
>   execution against the same SqlCommand object. Calling the
>   EndExecuteReader before the command's execution is completed cause the
>   SqlCommand object to block until the execution is finished.

This is the relevant section of code:

```
            // Although it is not required that you pass the 
            // SqlCommand object as the second parameter in the 
            // BeginExecuteReader call, doing so makes it easier
            // to call EndExecuteReader in the callback procedure.
            AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(HandleCallback);
            command.BeginExecuteReader(callback, command);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to immediately block (calling `EndExecuteReader`), you should just use [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352798) instead of `BeginExecuteReader`.

Comment: Hello Reed Copsey. Thanks for your answer. My objective is fill a DataGridView using the asyncronous methods of ADO.NET, but i can see which i don't use correctly this methods (or i confused how to use). Can you show me how to using correctly? (Sorry my english, i don't speak english)

Comment: @Ba3 Are you using .NET 4?  (It's far simpler there)